# B2 visa extension online for parents

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, visa-extensions

My Parents are stuck in US due to COVID 19. They are on a B2 visa and their authorized stay as per I-94 is expiring on June 30, 2020 and my mothers until 30 July 2020. We are in the process of filing a I-539 for extending their stay, they both entered the USA on different day (dad on 1st January, mother 1st February).

Is it ok if I apply now online for my dad and 20 days later for my mother?

Comment: Without any research this seems fine to me. Anything specifically you are concerned about?